# Problems building ffmpeg dlls on windows 32

Tags: ffmpeg, compilation, mingw

I'm trying to build ffmpeg dll files for windows 32 with mingw32.
at eatch try I manage to get some dll files but can't use theme because of a fiew dependancys that I can't get rid of.

Here is the packages that I use:

```
pkg-config
diffutils
yasm
make
mingw-w64-i686-toolchain
```

and there is the call to the configure script:

```
./configure 
 --disable-doc\
 --disable-decoders\ 
 --enable-decoder=h264\
 --enable-cross-compile\ 
 --disable-programs\
 --disable-avdevice 
 --disable-swresample 
 --disable-postproc\
 --disable-avfilter\ 
 --disable-encoders\ 
 --target-os=mingw32\ 
 --disable-static\ 
 --enable-shared\
 --shlibdir=SHARED_LIBS\
 --cxx=gcc --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm'\ 
 --disable-iconv\
 --extra-ldflags="-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc"
```

those are the dependancys :

```
libwinpthrad-1.dll
zlib1.dll
libbz2-1.dll
```

I don't know if my configuration or my mingw setup is wrond
thank you for the help.

Manou - french newbie

Answer (score 2):

Finally work for me with the folowing options:

```
 --disable-doc
 --disable-decoders
 --enable-decoder=h264
 --enable-decoder=hevc
 --enable-cross-compile
 --disable-programs
 --disable-avdevice
 --disable-swresample
 --disable-postproc
 --disable-avfilter
 --disable-encoders
 --target-os=mingw32
 --enable-shared
 --shlibdir=SHARED_LIBS
 --extra-ldflags="-static"
```

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg is quite a complex library with multiple dependencies.

You really need to have all the dependancies before you even try to start building.

When I build ffmpeg 5.0.1 for example I notice at least the following dependencies:

- zlib
- libbz2
- libdl
- freetype2
- libgsm
- lame
- libogg
- libvorbis
- libtheora
- opencore-amr
- librtmp
- schroedinger
- libspeex
- x264
- libxavs
- libvpx
- frei0r
- xvidcore
- celt

As for winpthread, that one comes with MinGW-w64, so you should already have that.

Comment: I managed to solve my problem using `--extra-ldflags="-static"` in the configure call thank you for your help